Expo EAS Build Stuck on Task :expo-modules-core:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease
I'm running into an issue while building my Expo app using EAS on Android. The build gets stuck during the lintVitalAnalyzeRelease task, specifically on the expo-modules-core package. Here's the relevant last portion of the build log:
> Task :react-native-maps:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-masked-view_masked-view:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-mmkv:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-picker_picker:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-reanimated:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-screens:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :react-native-screens:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease
> Task :expo-modules-core:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease

This build used to work fine, and I'm now encountering the same issue even after trying to build a previously successful version.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Reverting to a version that was built successfully.
Clearing build caches and trying a fresh build.
Running expo doctor to check for inconsistencies.
Updating dependencies to the latest versions.

Despite these steps, the build consistently gets stuck at expo-modules-core:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease.
Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any insights on how to fix it? I'd really appreciate any suggestions or guidance.
Expo SDK Version: ^51.0.14
EAS CLI Version: eas-cli/12.5.2 win32-x64 node-v21.6.2
React Native Version: 0.74.5
Thanks in advance!

I was dealing with the same issue for the past 3 days, and I couldn't find any errors in my project locally, but when I uploaded it, I encountered similar issues. After being stuck at the same point for 40 minutes, I managed to make some progress, which now shows other errors. What I did was upgrade the
eas/cli to 12.52.3
yesterday, and I also had a
.npmrc file with
legacy-peer-deps=true, which was preventing me from properly installing dependencies after deleting node_modules and package-lock.json. Additionally, I removed the things that were causing problems up to this point, which were the latest changes. I'm trying to solve everything little by little, and I hope that something I've done so far will work for you

npm install -g eas-cli
rn -rf node_module package-lock.json .npmrc
npm install



Had the same problem. What worked for me was updating expo
npx expo install expo

then clearing the cache:
npm cache clean --force

finally, I reinstalled the dependencies by removing node_modules and package-lock.json:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

and then
npm install

